# Display SecondaryCommands programmatically?

Tags: winrt-xaml, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1

How can I display SecondaryCommands programmatically?

By default, a user must tap the ellipses button to view the secondary commands.
In my case, I need to display the secondary commands on the bottom appbar based on a user-interaction?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show *SecondaryCommands* which means *open application bar* then just set [IsOpen property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbar.isopen):

```
BottomAppBar.IsOpen = true;
```

Comment: @ScottNimrod Hmm, as I've checked it 1 hour ago - it was working... Have you tired it?

Comment: Yes. What syntax are you using? Is it for WP8.1?

Comment: @ScottNimrod Yes, surely it's WP8.1 - can you [test the example](http://1drv.ms/1pWbWkg) - the app bar should open upon button click. Maybe you are trying to open it, when the appbar might be not ready - I've not tested it in `OnNavigatedTo`.

Comment: It only shows primary commands. It does not show full appbar with secondary commands.

Comment: @ScottNimrod That's very weird. I've tested it once again on both emulator and device - when I click *Show commands* button, the bottomappbar opens and I can see secondary command.  In this case I doubt I can help more.

Comment: I was attempting to do a BottomAppbar.Open when a button within the appbar is clicked. Thanks anyways though.